# how to enable debug on sass, so i can use firesass?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass

I am trying to install firesass - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/

it's asking me to add:

```
Sass::Plugin.options[:debug_info] = true
```

on config/environment.rb, but i can't find that file. Where can i exactly add that line?

I have windows 7 and I installed Ruby and sass like this: - http://damodarbashyal.hubpages.com/hub/Ruby-SASS-language-is-making-my-life-easier-to-manage-CSS-update

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The setup instructions are related to Rails.  If you used Rails, then you would have a file config/environment.rb inside your Rails project.

When invoking sass from the command line, you just need to add the flag `--debug-info`.

Comment: nice! that added debug line on css like this:

`@media -sass-debug-info{filename{font-family:file\:\/\/C\:\/_projects\/example\.com\.au\/master\/skin\/frontend\/enterprise\/xmpl\/css\/styles\.scss}line{font-family:\0000339}}`

But didn't show in firebug as firesass said.

Comment: Did you properly install the Firesass extension?  (Maybe you can upload your css on pastebin?!)

Comment: sorry didn't get notification. firefox installs itself, so should have been installed properly :)

Comment: Firesass is an external extension that you need to download :P

Comment: yes I did install through firefox addons. But I gave up fixing it now, Until i find step by step tutorial focusing on windows.